# Can we access all the account stacks and their information from AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, aws-cloudformation

Anther question to my [previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548135/aws-cloudformation-stack-in-all-regions/), Can we access all the account stacks and their information from AWS Lambda?

I have been asked to write a script to validate if all the stack-set have got created/updated in their appropriate region by putting their logs in the splunk.

Here's my approach- Create a simple python (AWS Lambda) script to validate all the region for their stackset and update its log information to the splunk (on each create or update of a stackset).

1. Hardcode all the accounts in the python script
   eg. accounts = [535353..., 435..., 645542..., etc]
2. Iterate over all accounts and their region using `python-trophosphere` or `boto3`
3. And for each region run a query to describe stack sets or describe events to validate (after a create/update script has run) whether the stackset has got create/updated.

Code excerpt would be:

```
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
description = client.describe_stack_set()
```

4. parse description to verify the status of the particular stackset for that account region
5. Update all that parsed description or (entire description) in the splunk logs.

But I'm not sure on:

- if I'd be able to access all the accounts and their regions from a
  lambda script.
- The approach is right or not

Suggest me a solution if I'm not on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done the way you described. However, in your lambda, you'll have to assume a role in each account before calling `describe_stack_set` to have the information for the right account (and possibly the right region). For automation sake, you might have to provision automatically the roles that trust the account in which the lambda is ran.

Another way to achieve this would be to distribute the Lambda on all accounts so you would skip the assume-role part and the hardcoding of account IDs.

My favorite way of doing this would be to create, either a custom resource or a scheduled lambda execution, inside each stacks that generate a log in Splunk that can be later queried. In Splunk you could trigger alerts when this specific log haven't showed up for a period of time.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. +1 for distributed lambda suggestion.